# How can I see what code is originally written to get this symbol?

Tags: html, symbols

in console I have this:

```
<div>♻</div>
```

The same in the page source code.

Copy-Paste in notepad++ - there is a rectangle instead the symbol.

How can I see what code is originally typed to get this symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below JavaScript for that.

```
var str_esc=escape('♻');

ans:%u267B
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert it to a HTML code (for example, `&#9851;`):

```js
var code = '♻'.codePointAt(0);
console.log('&#' + code + ';');
```